# Evitar que un select se abra estando con readonly

Tags: html, jquery

Saludos, tengo un `select` el cual esta deshabilitado con el atributo `readonly`, lo que quiero es evitar que se abra mientras esta con `readonly`, esto lo logro en este codigo 

`if ($(this).is('[readonly]')) {
            $(this).blur()
        }`
pero esto abre  y cierra el `select`, esto es lo que quiero evitar.
 
alguna idea de como podria ser?

**EDITO**
Este elemento se tiene que habilitar al realizar doble click sobre este por eso no utilizo disabled, esto ya esta hecho.
**pd**:uso botstrap y al estar con `readonly` toma un estilo de deshabilitado

```js
$(document).ready(documentoListo)
function documentoListo() {
 $("body").on("click",".drop",function(e){
  if ($(this).is('[readonly]')) {
                       //e.preventDefault()
   $(this).blur()
  }
 })
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="escolaridad" class="form-control reset inputt drop" readonly="readonly"><option value="0">Seleccione escolaridad</option><option value="1">Básica incompleta</option><option value="2">Básica completa</option><option value="3">Educación Media incompleta</option><option value="4">Educación Media completa</option><option value="5">Técnico nivel medio</option><option value="6">Técnico nivel superior</option><option value="7">Técnico profesional universitario</option><option value="8">Profesional universitario</option></select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno, ya que NO puedes usar listeners en elementos DESACTIVADOS, pues obtengo las primera coordena X donde comienza el select y donde termina (maxX) y lo mismo con la coordena Y.

Con este si cliquea entre el rango del mínimo valor de x y entre su máximo valor y a la vez lo mismo con la y, le sumará +1 a flags la cual controla la cantidad de clicks. Además el truco está en user en el css, `pointer-events: none;` que me permite escuchar el evento "click" dentro del elemento desactivado ( en este caso el select) , pero heredandoselo al body.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);

function main(){
    document.addEventListener("click",enable);
}
var flag = 0; 
  function enable(e) {
  var element = document.getElementById("Escolaridad"),
    posX = element.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    posY = element.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    maxX = posX + element.offsetWidth,
    maxY = posY + element.offsetHeight;
  var mouse = {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY}; 
  if( (mouse.x >= posX && mouse.x <= maxX)  &&
     (mouse.y >= posY && mouse.y <= maxY)
   ) { 
   if(flag === 1) {
     element.removeAttribute("disabled")
     document.body.setAttribute("style","pointer-events: initial")
     document.removeEventListener("click",enable);
   } 
   flag++; 
   }
  }
```

```css
body {
  pointer-events: none;
}
#Escolaridad {
position:relative;
border: 2px solid purple;
left: 150px;
top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<select disabled id="Escolaridad">
<option>Media</option>
<option>Básica</option>
<option>Kinder</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hola es lo que busco, pero los otros elementos no se pueden utilizar mientras el select esta disabled ¿hay alguna forma de evitar eso?

Comment: Si, haz un evento onfocus al documento, con el mismo pensamiento de las coordenadas, osea si el foco del mouse ( sin necesariamente haberlo cliqueado ) , se pondra el atributo pointer-events: none; al body, ya que recuerda que al hacer este "truco" podemos poner listeners en elementos DESACTIVADOS. Y por el contrario, si el foco no está entre las coordenadas del elemento ( en este caso el select) , pues lo dejas en pointer-events: initial, que es el valor por defecto

Comment: ok gracias me sirvio

Answer (score 1):

Para la etiqueta `<select>` no existe el atributo `readonly`, esto lo podrás verificar en la [Documentación de w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp), entonces debes cambiar el atributo por `disabled`

```html
<select id="escolaridad" class="form-control reset inputt drop" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="0">Seleccione escolaridad</option>
  <option value="1">Básica incompleta</option>
  <option value="2">Básica completa</option>
  <option value="3">Educación Media incompleta</option>
  <option value="4">Educación Media completa</option>
  <option value="5">Técnico nivel medio</option>
  <option value="6">Técnico nivel superior</option>
  <option value="7">Técnico profesional universitario</option>         <option value="8">Profesional universitario</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Si, no es un atributo propio del select, pero con disabled no puedo volver a habilitarlo al realizar doble click sobre el elemento, por esta razon use readonly

Comment: @Kevin entonces debes editar tu pregunta y redactarla mejor ya que esa parte no la mencionabas por ningún lado, saludos !