# ¿Hay alguna forma de ejecutar un evento cuando un botón esta en disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un formulario que cuando el usuario no ha terminado todos los campos el botón de envió esta en `disabled` hasta hay todo bien pero quiero que cuando el usuario le de **click** se ejecute una function que le muestre los `input` que faltan en rojo para que los termine de rellenar.

Pero no logro ejecutar ninguna function cuando esta disabled ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Les dejo un ejemplo de mas o menos lo que necesito e igual no me sale el 
`console.log()`.

De antemano muchas gracias.

```js
$("#enviar").click(function(){
  console.log("click en el boton que esta disabled")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="con-formulario">
    <label for="">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
    <label for="">Correo</label>
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
    <label for="">Clave</label>
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
  </div>
  
  <button disabled id="enviar" type="button" name="button">Enviar disabled</button>
```

Comment: Podrias ver mi respuesta aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/evitar-que-un-select-se-abra-estando-con-readonly/118929#118929

Comment: por favor acopla tu respuesta a mi pregunta porque no tienen mucho que ver gracias

Comment: Tiene todo que ver, de hecho mi respuesta es para esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un botón deshabilitado no genera el evento click, precisamente por estar deshabilitado.

No le veo mucho sentido a hacer algo así. Si deshabilitas un botón es para que el usuario entienda que no se puede pulsar, no tiene mucho sentido añadirle funcionalidad.

En cualquier caso, si lo quieres hacer así, puedes simular el comportamiento del atributo `disabled` con estilos css, dando apariencia de deshabilitado al botón y diferenciando el comportamiento del botón en el evento click en función de si tiene un estilo u otro.

Algo así:

```js
$(function(){
  $("input").change(function(){
    $("input").filter(function(){ return !this.value;}).length
      ? $("#enviar").addClass("disabled")
      : $("#enviar").removeClass("disabled");
  });
  $("#enviar").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")){
      $("input").filter(function(){ return !this.value;})
        .addClass("empty");
      $("input").filter(function(){ return !!this.value;})
        .removeClass("empty");
      console.log("quedan campos por rellenar");
      return;
    }
    $("input").removeClass("empty");
    console.log("Todo en orden. Enviar formulario")
  });
});
```

```css
input, button{
  display: block;
  margin: 4px;
}

#enviar.disabled{
  color: #666666;
}

input.empty{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="con-formulario">
    <label for="">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
    <label for="">Correo</label>
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
    <label for="">Clave</label>
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
  </div>
  
  <button id="enviar" class="disabled" type="button" name="button">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: muy buena respuesta gracias amigo